# SVG file custom font not showing in html

Tags: google-chrome, svg, printing, fonts

My goal: print an SVG to a single page (any paper size) full size from html page in Chrome (Electron).

I'm struggling to achieve this goal, here's my story:

I've generated an SVG that has text in it that should be displayed with a particular font. This is a custom font that I included with css (using Font Squirrel) and is also used for text in the website. When I display the SVG in my website inline the font renders fine.

Inline means it is an  element that is part of the dom that you can inspect. Problem with this is that you can't really change the width style without having to rerender the svg. Since I want to print it it would be nice to be able to do just 'width=100%'.

To do this I serialized the SVG to a dataURL and used an  and set its src to the dataURL. Now I can set the width like I want. However: the custom fonts don't work anymore!

So I saved the SVG img to file to edit it. Apparently you can include css in the SVG so that's what I did. Then when you open the file directly in browser it works right again. However when you open it in an IMG in a web page the fonts don't work anymore.

Next I tried copying svg fonts directly into the file ( glyph stuff...). Yes this works! Oh, no it doesn't, just in Safari not in Chrome, darn.

For now I'm considering to just rasterize it but that's no neat solution of course.

As you can understand I'm getting a bit frustrated here. Can anyone give me an insight in the SVG font issue or do you have any tips regarding the printing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution.

It turns out that files referenced in an IMG element cannot include any outside files for security reasons. So that's why referencing CSS in SVG doesn't work when showing it as IMG.

Also Chrome dropped support for SVG fonts. So even is you copy/paste SVG glyph data inside an SVG image it still doesn't work (really stupid). In Safari this works though.

So you need to reference WOFF font in css as a dataURL (base64). I did try this before but apparently I did something wrong. I tried it again and it works :).

I used FontSquirrel to generate this and I also subsetted the font there to only include the characters I actually need to save space.

It's not very efficient of course having to copy a font instead of referencing, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just not have any "text" in your SVG by converting your text to SVG paths.

You can do this in Inkscape by selecting your text and then going to Path->Object to Path. Then save or export everything into a new file, clear your browser cache, refresh, and now you should see your text.